# Laravel pierde la sesión al cambiar de página en react

Tags: laravel, reactjs, sesiones

Tengo un componente en react llamado Login que llama por fetch post a un controlador de laravel y me muestra los registros de una tabla. En este controlador de laravel creo una variable de sesion Session::put('val','valor'). Ahora cambio de url en react y muestro el componente Inicio que llama por fetch get a otro controlador de Laravel donde muestra los registros de una tabla y añade al array de registros la variable de session mencionada: array_push($users, Session::get('val')); El problema es que en react veo todos los registros y el último elemento del array es null

Espero un array de objetos con los registros de la tabla users y el último elemento del array espero que sea 'valor': [object1,object2,'valor']

Comment: Las variables de sesion se mantienen por defecto bajo la misma url base.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.